# Julia + GTK - global variable change in callback

Tags: gtk, julia

I am trying to learn Julia Language, and my current project is a "5 in a row" program. I started making an interface with Julia wrapper on Gtk for this game, but stumbled upon an interesting problem. Code is below.

The problem is: after callback function work cur_step variable is not changing, and labels of buttons are not changing too. However, if I delete the if-condition in the callback function, buttons will all get labels "x" after pressing as it is supposed to be right now.

I'm writing my code with Julia 1.0 in Jupyter Notebook.

I've tried to set up cur_step variable as global, since thought that it was a scope problem, but it didn't work out.

```
using Gtk

cur_step = "x"

function click_once_callback(widget)
    set_gtk_property!(widget, :sensitive, false)
    set_gtk_property!(widget, :label, cur_step)
    if cur_step == "x"
        cur_step = "o"
    else
        cur_step = "x"
    end
end

letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']

win = GtkWindow("GoMoku")
g = GtkGrid()

buttons = []

for i=1:15
    b = []
    for j=1:15
        letter = letters[i]
        push!(b,GtkButton("$letter:$j"))
    end
    push!(buttons,b)
end

for i=1:15
    for j=1:15
        g[i,16-j] = buttons[i][j]
        id = signal_connect(click_once_callback, buttons[i][j], "clicked")
    end
end


set_gtk_property!(g, :column_homogeneous, true)
set_gtk_property!(g, :column_spacing, 15)  # introduce a 15-pixel gap between columns
set_gtk_property!(g, :row_spacing, 15)  # introduce a 15-pixel gap between rows
push!(win, g)
showall(win)
```

Why is it so that global variable not changing through the callback function? I expect to change cur_step iteratively after each button was clicked.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to label cur_step as global *inside* your function (as well as outside, for good code signposting).

A function can use a variable from its parent scope without problems, as long as there's no assignment anywhere within the function's scope. If there is an assignment somewhere (even if it's in an if block), then the function is interpreted as local; this is true even prior to the point where its assignment occurs.

In order to treat a variable that gets assigned at some point inside the function properly as a global one, you need to explicitly point this out inside the function by using `global cur_step`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. How did I miss this in Julia tutorials?